# MessageBox never appears?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

This is the code i use for exiting the app,

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        MessageBoxResult m = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure, Do you want to exit this application", "Exit Warning", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
        if (m == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            e.Cancel = false;
            //MessageBox.Show("Working ON Exiting the app!");
            if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
                {
                  while (NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry() != null)
                   {
                     NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
                   }
                }

        }
    }
```

The problem is that message box never appears and the value of `m` is taken as `Cancel`.
What could be the problem?

Comment: WPF and Windows Phone tags, are you mixing things up?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd I added that (one answerer thought this was about WinForms), was it a mistake? I'll remove it again.

Comment: Problem is not with closing!! It is only with messagebox. Because MessageBox never shows(not only in this case but in all other case where it is used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
MessageBoxResult m = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure, Do you want to exit this application", "Exit Warning", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
```

will not be a wise decision, because when you keep it idle (without pressing ok or cancel) for sometime your application will exit automatically.

Pls avoid this technique!!